# VBA How to delete the improper discrete lines

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to delete some lines whose sixth cell doesn't contain the correct value. And Here is my code:

```
dim i As Integer
for i = 1 to Row
    If Worksheets("Data").Cells(i,6).Text <>"a" Then
        Worksheets("Data").Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
```

And I've found that if I delete line 1 (aaa), then the former line 2(bbb) becomes line 1, perhaps it's not the line that I want to keep, but i has already became 2, so actually I missed this line (bbb) and remove directly to the former line 3 (ccc).

```
1 aaa => bbb
2 bbb => ccc
3 ccc
```

And I don't know if there is a good algorithm for this problem? Thank you.

Comment: why not just have a simple solution here, if you go inside your `If` , then after you delete the row, just add a row `i = i - 1`

Comment: Oh so I always begain from the former line where I deleted one?

Comment: if you delete a line, then yes. you don't want to skip a line

Comment: And also you need to assign new value to `Row` variable. Because if you are going to delete all rows then i will be always 1 and Row will have some greater value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're deleting rows it's best to work from the bottom up.
Change `for i = 1 to Row` to `for i = Row to 1 Step -1`.

Now when you delete a row it won't alter the row number of any rows above it.

Answer (score 3):

Always iterate backwards from last to first when deleting.

```
dim i As Integer
for i = Row to 1 Step -1
    If Worksheets("Data").Cells(i,6).Text <>"a" Then
        Worksheets("Data").Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's do it in reverse order . try to modify the below code as your wish.

```
Sub Deleterows()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    lRow = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' calculates no of rows used in A column

    For iCntr = lRow To 6 Step -1 ' loop in reverse order
        If Cells(iCntr, 1) = "str" Then 'You can change this text
            Sheets("Data").Rows(iCntr).Delete
        End If
    Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quiet understand, `lRow` is the number of rows I have in this sheet? then I go from the last one row `lRow` to 6, is that?

Comment: Correct ! .Irow is the number of rows used in the A column

Comment: Ok I see! Thank you very much, but I have to choose one as an answer and Mr. Darren comes first so... Well still your answer's perfect!

Comment: No worries. @Darren's answer is short & Perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the while loop so that you could reduce the iterations as well as the limit of the loop after deleting a row, see below

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim rows As Integer
row_count = 3
i = 1

While i <= row_count
    If Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 6).Text <> "a" Then
        Worksheets("Data").rows(i).Delete
        i = i - 1
        row_count = row_count - 1
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend
```